# Creating an app that saves user's input to a text file with Kotlin

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, mobile-application

I need to create an Android app that takes user input via a textview and saves it to a text file. I have created a button that should enable this activity. but when I press the button on the emulator, the app crashes. This is the code that I am using:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    button.setOnClickListener {
        val product = productName.text.toString()
        val Filename = "data.txt"
        File("data.txt").writeText(product)
    }
}
```

}

Do you know what the problem is here? is there any better way to code this activity?

Thank you

Comment: File(getFilesDir(), "data.txt").writeText(product) as you have to supply a full path. Not only a file name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't provided the directory path while declaring file.

You can achieve the functionality simply by using the below code.

```
File root = new File(DIRECTORY_PATH);
File file = new File(root, "data.txt");
FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(file);
writer.append("Your text here from textView");
writer.flush();
writer.close();
```

You can use the DIRETCORY_PATH as :- Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() or if you created any specific directory then you can do ths :- Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()+"/Your Directory/"